# Keeping text in an alert view, and saving text to an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uialertview

I have a `UITableView` that is meant have a list of names. I want it to bring up an `UIAlertView` whenever a name is clicked, so that the accompanying information to the name (for now just the age) will be allowed to be changed.

As of now, I can get an `alertView` with a `UITextField` to appear, however once you close the alertView, the `text` inside the `UITextField` resets to the placeholder. How can I get the text to stay with the `UIAlertView`?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIAlertView *alert = 
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set Age" 
                               message:[_tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                              delegate:nil 
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.placeholder = @"18";
    [alert show];
}
```

Also, how can I get the text from the `UIAlertView`, and save it as a `NSString`?

Thank you!

Comment: In the delegate method of `UIAlertView`: `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, retrieve its `UITextField` text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your view controller as the delegate and then retrieve the value in the callback. You also need to add `UIAlertViewDelegate` to your `@interface`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set Age" message:[_tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.placeholder = @"18";
    [alert show];
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        return;
    }

    NSString * yourString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text

}
```

Comment: You can set the delegate in the `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles` method.